# How to find out what encoding a file has

Tags: java, cryptography

Does anyone got any good ideas on how to find out what kind of encoding is used on a certain text.
I got this text :
 `frqrzvupeN/ :fv yriry gkra ruG !rgnz obw qbT` 
But I got no clue what kind of encoding it is or how to find it out.

Comment: It's [ROT13](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ROT13), and the string is also reversed.

Answer (score 1):

These kind of puzzles are normally some sort of [substitution cipher](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Substitution_cipher) most likely a Caesar cipher. You can see that it is not a modern cipher because the ciphertext only contains normal characters (and not a binary encoding). The fact that the spaces and special characters are maintained hint at a simple alphabet substitution. Furthermore, it is likely in reverse as all the sentences end with a capital letter.

The best way to crack this is to guess the letter substitutions and check if the sentence makes sense. With a computer you could do the same thing and leave only those sentences where the words are in a dictionary.

Obviously, as ntoskrnl has pointed out, with these kind of things you can also test against a rotational cipher, with Rot13 being the most used. A rotational cipher is a simple substitution cipher.